# Is there R function to calculate variance covariance matrix of AR model

Tags: r

I use ar.ols() to fit a AR(p) model,but vcov() can not be used to AR model.So is there R function to calculate variance covariance matrix of AR model. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be a little more specific, and give a [mcve]?  Do you want the (estimated) covariance matrix of the *observations* in an AR model? Or the covariance of the sampling distribution of the *parameters*?

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new, and I want variance-covariance matrix of the main parameters of a fitted model object, just like what the vcov() do to an ols model.